# JSON children only got the first child in PHP

Tags: php, json, foreach

Been trying all day to do what would appear to be something quite simple and I'm failing to get all children nodes from json (only got the first child within this code):

```
foreach($obj->data[0]->region as $code_id) {              
    echo $code_id->code_id . "\n"; 
        
}
```

JSON snippet below:

```
{
"data": [
        {
        "record_id": 9,
        "region": [
            {
                "code_id": 2,
                "code_name": "CA"
            },
            {
                "code_id": 3,
                "code_name": "WY"
            }
           
        ]
        },
        {
        "record_id": 10,
        "region": [
            {
                "code_id": 4,
                "code_name": "CA"
            },
            {
                "code_id": 5,
                "code_name": "WY"
            }
           
        ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Any link or suggestion for tutorial really appreciate :(

Comment: You will get  first child nodes only because you accessing first index only `$obj->data[0]`.

Comment: `data[0]` you will get first index only.

Comment: Do you want to give  more details?

Comment: I am also tried like this, but return blank white page: 

    ```foreach ($arr as $key => $value) {
     if ($key == 'data') {
      foreach ($value as $key2 => $val2) {
       foreach ($val2 as $key3 => $val3) {
         if($key3=='region');
         
         var_dump($key4);
        }
       }
      }
     }
    }```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to loop over both arrays, the following will work:

```php
// Loop over everything inside of data
foreach($obj->data as $thing ) {
    // Loop over each region
    foreach($thing->region as $region) {
        echo $region->code_id . "\n";
    }
}
```

The output is:

```php
2
3
4
5
```

Demo here: https://3v4l.org/NQTV6

Comment: Thanks Sir, It works properly. Big thanks. I saw double foreach on your code. I will noted this

Answer (score 0):

try this...

Not the most optimised solution but should get you back on track.

```
foreach($obj->data[0] as $record) { 
    if(isset($record->region)){
        foreach($record->region as $code){
            echo $code->code_id . "\n";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank's for suggestion. Your code worked too Sir